# Why this function has weak type when i use function keyword? OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let duplicates =
  let rec duplicates' accumulator = function
    | [] -> accumulator
    | [ item ] -> duplicates' (item :: accumulator) []
    | item :: item2 :: tail ->
      if item = item2 then duplicates' (item :: accumulator) tail
      else duplicates' (item::accumulator) (item2::tail)
  in
  duplicates' [];;
```

If I add a second parameter that must be a 'a list and use "match with" on it the code works.

(also: the end of codes and with: in duplicates [] 'parameter')

If I use function keyword and make the code more concise, the function returns:

```
val duplicates : '_weak14 list -> '_weak14 list = <fun>
```

Comment: Style suggestion: use `acc` for your accumulator. It's easier to type and a pretty common habit, meaning others should still know what you're doing. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the value restriction. Your function `duplicates` is defined not by a value (i.e., a lambda) but as an application: `duplicates' []`. So it can't be generalized.

You can fix this using eta expansion:

```
# let duplicates list =
  let rec duplicates' accumulator = function
    | [] -> accumulator
    | [ item ] -> duplicates' (item :: accumulator) []
    | item :: item2 :: tail ->
      if item = item2 then duplicates' (item :: accumulator) tail
      else duplicates' (item::accumulator) (item2::tail)
  in
  duplicates' [] list ;;
val duplicates : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
#
```

This works because `duplicates` is now defined as a lambda using the compact notation `let f x = e`, equivalent to `let f = fun x -> e`.

The value restriction is documented in Section 6  of the OCaml manual, ["Polymorphism and its limitations."](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/htmlman/polymorphism.html)

I've found the following paper extremely helpful in thinking about the value restriction: [Garrigue, Jacques; Relaxing the Value Restriction](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf).